# How to include files in RubyMine after excluding them

Tags: rubymine

I exclude some of files in my Ruby Mines project. 
Accidentally the whole project was excluded,How can i re-include the whole project in Ruby Mines ?

Answer (score 0):

How did you exclude them?

The usual way to exclude / include back directories in the project is to go to the main **Settings → Project Structure**. From there you can simply click a directory and (un)mark it as excluded. See [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/project-structure-dialog.html?origin=old_help) for this feature.